# Can I use "The Google of" as a marketing text for a search engine?

Tags: title

I've got a search engine and I'm wondering,

- can I legally use "the Google of [some special thing]" as a marketing text for a search engine?
- will I get punished by Google ranking for this?

Comment: or sued for trademark infringement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You will be punished.  For sure.   And it won't be via ranking.

I was threatened for using the word *goggle* as an obvious google substitute.

Comment: Wow, that sounds pretty bad. :/ 
It is funny that a few hundred years ago it was considered a form of respect if someone was copied (Mozart copied too, left and right) and now we live in the age of companies whose names we can't even say publicly out loud. (see zumba can't be put on a t-shirt and so on... duh)

Comment: How did they come after you?

Comment: I received an email from my ISP that they had been contacted by Google with a takedown notice.  I had 48 hours to remove it or they would :P

Comment: Wow, so they contacted the ISP right away. Ok, that sounds bad enough.